# Tricky: Remap url but stay on the same url internally

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Need your help. Just spend many ours on this htaccess problem and still don't have a clue how to manage this.

I have many http://www.example.com/menu-alias/foo links on my company's website which should get redirected to http://www.example.com/foo.

This alone shouldn't be the hard part but listen up... the tricky part follows.

I don't manage to get the site (Joomla 1.5) working without the 'menu-alias' this means that all http://www.example.com/foo should get internally mapped to http://www.example.com/menu-alias/foo. So that the user still has http://www.example.com/foo in his browser's address bar.

To make it even more complicated i have to 301 redirect the old menu-alias/foo links to /foo.

Can some htaccess guru help me out? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding these rules in the htaccess file in your document root (or vhost config):

```
RewriteEngine On

# externally redirect requests that have "menu-alias"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /menu-alias/([^\ \?]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]

# internally rewrite requests back to menu-alias
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/menu-alias/
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /menu-alias/$1 [L]
```

Couple of potential problems:

1. Joomla may be looking for the original un-rewritten request in `$_SERVER`, if so, the rewrite won't work.
2. The rule to add the `/menu-alias/` back into the URI does so blindly rewrites all requests that don't point to an existing resource. This means "virtual" paths that Joomla may handle will get a "menu-alias" appended to the front.